# Why am I NOT able to install new themes in Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, themes

I have installed `Kubuntu 22.04`. I am NOT able to install any theme
which is available to install. If I press `Install` button, I am getting error  :

[image]

#### Edit 1:

I am also NOT able to install `Kwin scripts` :

[image]

Comment: Difficult to help based on fuzzy information like "some theme".

Comment: Try it in the command line with `apt`.

Comment: @vanadium Not only `some theme` I meant `any theme` which is available to install.

Comment: Thanks for correcting. Comments are there to help people improve a question or an answer.